# What should i do if my college refused to issue me a degree after paying off my debt?

Tags: graduation

I'm an African American. I had all my degrees here in the United States, my Bsc and my two masters degrees. Guess what? I was refused a diploma for my EMBA bcos i couldn't pay a just bal of $1050 on my student account. Of course it was "pay from the pocket option". I paid off the outstanding balance yet i could obtain my diploma because i did not apply for a graduation at the year i completed my program. Therefore, i was told my diploma will be dated current yrs (2 years after) despite i took graduation foto and attended the graduation ceremony. I'm still confuse i can be denied of my diploma even after paying off the balance. I'm in search of a lawyer who can help me with this case. Why will this college refuse to issue me a diploma stating the year i complete the course after paying off? As for the graduation application, i did sunmitted it of which i called their attention to check the email. Unfortunately, the school said they can not retrieve two years back email of a student. Can you imagine?
What should i do if my college refused to issue me a degree after paying off my debt?
 Pls i need your advice on this issue folks. Thnks

Comment: If you are talking to a lawyer, take their advice. Nothing here can help you. Your college rules are what they are.

Comment: This is not a place for legal advice. Try contacting the ones responsible at the university to make your case, if possible go there in person. Look for student representation, student counsels or something of the kind that might be able to help you.

Comment: Are they refusing to grant you a degree, or is it that degree conferral is delayed until the next semester?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a legal question about the particulars of the case. Perhaps this can be migrated to Law.SE?

Comment: @jakebeal: Legal advice on specific cases is [explicitly off-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [law.se].

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I see; not sure this belongs anywhere on SE, then.